# SelectedValue not binding for some of the Html.dropdownlist in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, drop-down-menu, html-helper, selectedvalue

I got 3 `html.dropdownlists` out of which only for 1 its the setting the `selectedvalue`.How come its binding for one of the dropdownlist not for the other 2.In the Quick Watch,all the values are proper, it even shows which value has its selected=true. but in the page it doesnt get set.
Is there any solution for this?

```
Function Index(ByVal custdetails As Customer, ByVal CCDetails As CreditCard)
   As ActionResult

   txn=mysession.getdata(mysession.activesession) 

End Function
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the Controller and View?

Comment: That would be a whole lot of code to be pasted?? but has anyone not faced this problem??